# sharepoint sandbox solution use spribbon class

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

I want to add contextual tab. Using farm solution i am able to add contextual webpart

this is my code using that i am able to add contextual Tab in farm solution

```
 SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page).MakeTabAvailable("MyProject.Ribbon.HelloTab");
```

in sandbox solution this code not working because SPRibbon class not working.

Is that any other way to add contextual tab in sandbox solution

reply me fast,It's fast

Answer (score 1):

The SPRibbon class isn't available in a sandboxed solution, because the sandboxed solution doesn't has access to the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls namspace.

The way to interact with the server ribbon in a sandboxed solution is by using a page component (ECMA script). Here is a link to an example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407303.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done in the Sandbox I'm afraid: *["It seems that contextual tabs/groups can only be made available by server-side code, and note also that SPRibbon is not available in the sandbox."](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/adding-ribbon-items-into-existing.html)* (about 1/3 of the way through the post.)